# SQL invalid column name when it exists after doing date conversion

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query where I convert the timestamp to a date, and then try to group to get daily aggregates.

```
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DateTime, 103) as [date], MIRN, sum(Usage)
from table
group by [date], MIRN
```

The issue is I get an error message saying:

> Invalid column name 'date'

I have tried doing the ctrl+shift+r trick and it didn't help.

[screenshot of non-aggregated results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XsXYU.png)

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is because a `GROUP BY` is always executed before the `SELECT` clause.

There are several possible fixes:

(1) Put the `CONVERT` part also in the `GROUP BY`:

```
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DateTime, 103) as [date], MIRN, sum(Usage)
from table
group by CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DateTime, 103), MIRN
```

(2) Use a CTE (Common Table Expression):

```
WITH myCTE AS (
    select CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DateTime, 103) as [date], MIRN, Usage
    from table
)
SELECT x.date, x.MIRN, sum(x.Usage)
FROM myCTE x
group by x.date, x.MIRN
```

(3) Use a sub-query:

```
SELECT x.date, x.MIRN, sum(x.Usage)
FROM (
    select CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DateTime, 103) as [date], MIRN, Usage
    from table
) x
group by x.date, x.MIRN
```